# Android facebook integration invalid key hash?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

Android Facebook Login problem, I have successfully integrate Facebook sdk into my Application using this Tutorial [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) , When i login at first time it's work as i want, But after logout and i came back to the login it's display Toast like below.

"This app has no Android key hashes configured. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxx"

But I have check it twice, I have configure app key hashes properly. Am I doing something wrong or what?